# El código difiere de la imagen como debe quedar

Tags: bootstrap-4

Según el siguiente código de bootstrap debería quedar como a continuación muestra la imagen:

[image: De esta forma debería quedar]

Pero me está quedando de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
  <div class="card-header">{{ titulo }}</div>
    <div class="card-body">

      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="custom-file">
          <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile04" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04">
          <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile04">Subir foto</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="inputGroupFileAddon04">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Estoy trabajando con Angular 7, las dependencias las tengo instaladas en el proyecto, me sirvió su respuesta. Solo tuve que actualizar las dependencias y quedó correctamente la visualización del código:                                                         Primero quitas las dependencias:

npm uninstall bootstrap jquery popper.js

Luego la vuelves a instalar actualizadas:

npm install bootstrap@latest jquery popper.js --save

Una vez echo esto ya puedes volver a levantar tu app.

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo el código con las correcciones para obtener el resultado. Saludos!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
  <div class="card-header">Detalle del cliente</div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile04" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile04">Seleccionar un archivo</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="inputGroupFileAddon04">Subir</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```